# JSのFileReaderAPIで読み込んだ画像バイナリを、JavaのImageIOで読み込みたい

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, java8, base64

JavaScriptのFileReaderで読み込んだ画像データを、サーバーサイドで加工のためBufferedImageに変換したいのですが、うまく変換できません。

画像はWorkerを使った非同期ロードで取得し、
Ajaxでサーバーサイドに送信しています。

worker.js

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var reader = new FileReaderSync();

    var file_data = reader.readAsDataURL(e.data.file);
    request({
                 url: "/post",
                 data: {
                           file : file_data
                       },
                 success: function() {
                     alert("success");
                 }
           });
}, false);
```

PostController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/post", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@RequestParam("file") String fileUri) {
    // 引数は "data:image/jpeg;base64,略//2Q==" という形式
    InputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                      fileUri.getBytes("UTF-8")
                                 );
    // read結果はnull;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(byteStream);
}
```

ちなみに、引数であるbase64文字列を、base64デコードしようとすると、下記のようなエラーが発生します。

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 3a
```

また、base64エンコードされたデータをブラウザで確認した際は、選択した画像が正常に表示されます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64デコードするときはヘッダー部を除去しなければならないことを忘れていました。

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/post", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String post(@RequestParam("file") String fileUri) {
    // 引数は "data:image/jpeg;base64,略//2Q==" という形式
    InputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                  Base64.getDecoder().decode(
                                       fileUri.replaceAll("^[^,]+,", "")
                                  );
                             );
    // read結果はnull;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(byteStream);
}
```

とすることで解決しました。